# What is the Origin of "wouldn't say boo to a goose"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, popular-refrains

According to http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/Question284368.html this is the origin of the phrase "wouldn't say boo to a goose":

> Because of the supposed stupidity of the bird of that name, the word 'goose' has meant a simpleton since the 1500s. The word 'boo' in this context is the sudden, loud version of it...the one adults sometimes use to surprise or 'frighten' children...rather than the disapproving anti-cheering version. So, 'saying boo to a goose' - whether human or avian - is about the least brave thing one could imagine doing and, as a result, very shy people are accused of being unable to do even that.
>   [quizmonster](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/members/quizmonster/)

This seems strange because I have always thought of geese as aggressive animals that you wouldn't want to startle.

Is there any evidence that this is the correct origin?

Comment: Geese around their eggs are particularly aggressive, as are ones that are used to being fed by humans

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Phrase Finder confirms the origin, but Etymonline probably explains the rationale behind the saying in a clearer way:

***[Say boo to a goose](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/55/messages/666.html):***

> - It's just a country proverb, perfectly clear to anyone who is familiar with geese, as in earlier centuries virtually all rural European people would have been. ***Anybody who shouts loudly and firmly at geese can intimidate them; indeed minding geese was traditionally a job for small girls.*** Anybody who doesn't dare say "Boo!" to a goose really is a wimp. (VSD)

***[boo to a goose](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boo):***

> - To be able to say Bo! to a goose is to be not quite destitute of courage, to have an inkling of spirit, and was probably in the first instance used of children. ***A little boy who comes across some geese suddenly will find himself hissed at immediately, and a great demonstration of defiance made by them, but if he can pluck up heart to cry 'bo!' loudly and advance upon them, they will retire defeated.*** The word 'bo' is clearly selected for the sake of the explosiveness of its first letter and the openness and loudness of its vowel. [Walter W. Skeat, "Cry Bo to a Goose, "Notes and Queries," 4th series vi Sept. 10, 1870]

(Etymonline)

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I got nipped hard.